# Converter fails using forClass on a superclass

Tags: jsf, converters

I'm trying to create a global converter to my objects. This converter will serialize and deserialize any object that extends my Model class.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import javax.faces.component.EditableValueHolder;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

import org.jboss.security.Base64Utils;

import util.base.Model;

@FacesConverter(forClass=Model.class)
public class ModelConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,     String string) {
        Model obj = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new     ByteArrayInputStream(Base64Utils.fromb64(string));
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            obj  = (Model)ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            EditableValueHolder comp = (EditableValueHolder) component;
                comp.addValidator(context.getApplication().createValidator("modelValidator"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,     Object obj) {
        String str = "";
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.close();
            oos.reset();
            str = Base64Utils.tob64(baos.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }

}
```

The getAsString method is called correctly when the page is rendered but the getAsObject method is never called. I'm wouldn't like to use the f:converter tag or the "converter" attribute.

XHTML snippet:

```
<f:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="category" value="#{recordBean.record.category}">
        <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Selecione" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{recordBean.categories}" var="category" itemLabel="#{category}" itemValue="#{category}"  />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Salvar" action="#{recordBean.save}" icon="ui-icon-disk" />
</f:form>
```

I'm using primefaces but with standard JSF tags I got the same error: value is not valid.

Putting forClass=Object.class, getAsObject is called.

Comment: What components is submitting the value and what build of JSF are you running? Also, are you absolutely sure that a value is being submitted?

Comment: @kolossus I'm sure. The "value is not valid" is returned by JSF. Added a snippet and more info.